# How do I selectively mark books read by a user in the frontend if I have a common dataset of books and a dataset of the particular books read?

Tags: python, django

I have a "Books" model in django which stores information like the name, author etc (irrelevant here, just mentioning for some context). I display all that information using a Paginator and each user has the option of marking the books he/she has read. To mark them, what I can think of doing is creating another model called "BookStatus" where I insert new entries every time a user reads a book. I also thought of doing this because I want to store additional information like the time at which the book was read and how long the user spent reading it. However, I'm unable to figure out how to actually display that the user has read some particular book next to the book's name while displaying it in the frontend. What would be the easiest way to accomplish this?

In short, I have a database of books which are common to all users. For each user I want to store the books he/she has read along with the time at which they read it and how long they took to do so (all entered by the user) and while displaying those common books I want to be able to mark them as read/unread on the frontend.

Comment: Just add a manytomany field in your books Model something like `read_by = models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True,null=True)` you can check in the template if the user is in read_by then it means he reads that book else he did not read it.

Comment: take boolean field . Like : has_read = models.BooleanField(default=Flase)
then update the field when user read the book.

Comment: @mehedi sorry after seeing your comments I realised that I can't do that because I want to store some additional info as well. Edited my question.

Comment: add datetime field(open time) and duration field(read time)  in database .
when user open the book hit a post request to your api to add open time .
then start counting time with js . when user close the tab or exit from reading hit  api for update duration time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right track. Here's an example of what you can do:

```
class BookStatus(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='book')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user')
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    duration = models.DurationField(blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username} is reading {self.book.name}"
```